# SuiteScript 2 file.File wrong parameter type

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am attempting to attach a file to an email, the file gets created, I am passing in the internal id of the invoice but it is throwing an error "Wrong parameter type: options.attachments is expected as file.File[]. ", I am passing in the file object as the singular element of an array. When I look at the variable in the debugger it shows as file.File as an element of an array. So it is the right type. Does anyone know what could be wrong. Here is test code I am debugging.

```
        var file = renderModule.transaction( {
            entityId : 479772,//internal id of the transaction
            printMode: 'pdf',
            formId   : 111
        } );


        //noinspection AmdModulesDependencies
        var subject = "Test Subject"
        var options = {};
        options.author = 13136; //autoSendParams.senderId;
        options.recipients = 'jk@zognet.com';
        options.replyTo = 'ar@cbcbev.com';
        options.subject = 'test subject';
        options.body = "test";
        options.relatedRecords = {transaction:479772}
        options.attachments = [ file ]
        emailModule.send( options );
```

Here is the debugger output for the attachments variable that I am passing in

```
attachments = {array} length=1
[0] = {file.File}  
type = {string} file.File
id = {object} null
name = {string} Invoice_CBC:384463-IN.pdf
description = {object} null
path = {string} Invoice_CBC:384463-IN.pdf
url = {object} null
folder = {number} -1
fileType = {string} PDF
isText = {boolean} false
size = {number} 14191
encoding = {object} null
isInactive = {boolean} false
isOnline = {boolean} false
```

Comment: Interesting; I don't see what's wrong with this. I have some very similar code that basically does `options.attachments = [ render.transaction(...) ];` and it's working correctly. Only difference is that I don't declare `options` outside of the `send` invocation, but I don't see why that would make a difference.

Comment: Yea, I am kinda stumped I had similar code in another project that is working fine. As you can see I basically made it as simple as possible and nothing. For grins, I will try it the way you are doing it as I have run out of things to check, thanks for all your help.

Comment: Nope, it didn't help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your relatedRecords property should be an object like so:

```
relatedRecords = {transaction:479772}
```

Comment: thanks, yea, I caught that and it still gave the same error, I would greatly appreciate any type of help with this I am in a crunch.

Comment: What happens when you log the name and/or body of the file? Also is ‘file’ used anywhere else as a variable name in your script? You’re not importing N/file into a variable named ‘file’?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need the solution for this.

1 of the reason is that you extend / add some method to Javascript object prototype (even if you don't call this method in your code)

For example having this snippet in your .js file will be the root cause

```
Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
            var total = 0
            for (var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++) {
                total += this[i][prop]
            }
            return total
        }
```

Comment: It ended up being string manipulation in a library module. But good call, I never manipulate the prototype but good guess none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue `error.SuiteScriptError","name":"WRONG_PARAMETER_TYPE","message":"Wrong parameter type: options.attachments is expected as file.File[].`

Answer:
I manipulated `Array.prototype` in a module and its causing a downstream affect.